# Passing a php value to modal using plain javascript without jquery or ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to pass values from `PHP` to a **modal box** using plain `Javascript`? I researched here in SO and found that most of the answers are either `JQuery` or `AJAX`. I'd like to know how because I'm new in `Javascript` and `PHP` so I'd like to first have a thorough practice and understanding in `Javascript` before diving into `JQuery` and `AJAX`.

I'm working on a small project which has a modal box and a `<table>` with an **Edit** control.

```
<div id="modalBox" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-container">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('modalBox').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
            <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
            <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="record-container">
    <table class="table-record">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Control</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
        $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent();
        foreach($announcementList as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key->getTitle(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->getDateAdded(); ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox')">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Let's say I want to fill the modal box with the value returned by `$value->getDateAdded`, is that possible without `JQuery` and `AJAX`?

How can I go about it? Can you provide some ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `showEditModal` could store the value in an html data attribute, and then retrieve when the modal javascript code executes.

Comment: You can add another parameter in `showEditModal()` function and pass the value of $value->getDateAdded to that.

Comment: @Mr.Blue Your suggestion works but I'd like to pass `$value` object to javascript function `showEditModel()` then from within the method's block I like to access the `get()` methods. I can't figure out how to do that using `json_encode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please replace your code with these lines from below code.

 // Add id where you want to add this
id="subjectdiv" 

// On click add your php value

onclick="showEditModal('modalBox','<?php echo $value->getDateAdded(); ?>')"

function showEditModal(modalid,phpval) {

//You code here

//code for send value on modal box
var theDiv = document.getElementById("subjectdiv");
theDiv.innerHTML = phpval; 

}

Hope this can help.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works. Would you know how I can access the `get()` methods of the php object from within the javascript method like `var obj = JSON.parse(phpobject);` then `obj->getX()` ?

Comment: What do you want exactly, Can you  inbox me please?

Comment: Actually, I'm now able to get the values to show on the `<div>` but now what I'm trying to do is pass the PHP object as object to my `showEditModal()` method. From within the block I'd like to access the object's property.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax IS plain JavaScript. But if you're just trying to echo something in PHP to the client to be run as JavaScript, you're looking for [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did some research and I think I'm getting how I can us `json_encode` to parse. Is it possible to parse a php object which has `getters()`so that I can access the object's getters within js function's block like `var obj = JSON.parse(phpobject);` then `obj->getSomething()` ?

Comment: @p3ace There's no need to parse proper JSON from a trusted source as JSON. Simply assign it to a variable in JavaScript and it becomes your object. `<script>var obj=<?= json_encode($phpObject); ?>;alert(obj.something);</script>`